# reading config file in kohana 3.2

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

hi friends i know how to read config file in kohana 3.0
my code is

```
 $config_file = Kohana::config('ratna');
 $value = $config_file['name'];
```

here `ratna`is `config file` like below

```
    <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
   return array(
     'name' => 'Clarence Ratna',
     'tag_line' => "Let's talk about me!",
       'qualification'=>"MCA"
   );
```

my question is how read same file in kohana 3.2 ???

```
Kohana::config('ratna'); method is not working in 3.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Kohana::$config->load('ratna');
```

You can find more information in [official docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/config)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Config load function.

```
$config =     Kohana::$config->load('database');
//To get Specific Value
//$value = $config->get('Your_Variable');
$name  = $config->get('name');
```